# css navigation and logo same position issue

Tags: html, css

I need to place logo image and navigation bar on same direction.

Here is my html code:

```
<div id = "header">
<div class = "wrap">
<div class = "logo">
<img src = "img/photo.jpg" alt = "" /> 
</div>
<nav class = "navigation">
<ul>
<li><a href = "#">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href = "#">ABOUT</a> </li>
<li><a href = "#">HAIRSTYLES</a> </li>
<li><a href = "#">NEWS</a> </li>
<li><a href = "#">CONTACT</a> </li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
body
{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:14px;
}
#header {
        float:left;
        min-width:100%;
        background-color:Aqua;
    }
    #header .logo
    {
        width:400px;
        float:left;
    }
    #header nav 
    {
        width:400px;
        float:right;
    }
.wrap
{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:900px;
}
nav ul li
{
    display:inline-block;
    padding-right:10px;
    list-style:none;
}
nav ul li a
{
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:link, a:active, a:visted
{
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover
{
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:Fuchsia;
}
```

Result look like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hCR5.jpg

So i need navigation bar and logo place on same direction.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this helps you. Remove the floats for `#header .logo` and `#header nav` and make these divs `display:inline-block`. [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/h7wr383v/)

```
#header .logo,
#header nav 
{
    width:400px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: if i add one more li in my navigation, it shows like this http://imgur.com/0xFGKvm may i know how to fix this, and i need to do same margin for navigation too, now margin-left and margin-right didn't same.

Comment: This is happening because you have specified `width:400px;` to the divs. I would suggest you to remove the width for both the divs and give a margin-right to the div containing the log so that there is a space b/w the logo and nav. This is help the nav to take the rest of the space left on the right side.

Comment: okay @james: so now i did, margin-right:300px; to #header .logo. It looks correct that what i want.. but this is the standard format?

Comment: @selva you can't really say it's the standard format. What inline-block does is arrange the two divs inline and will take the width of its contents, so it's not necessary to specify the width for the divs unless you need the width to be specified explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
#header .logo
    {
        width:400px;
        float:left;
    }
```

to:

```
#header .logo
    {
        width:400px;
        float:right;
    }
```

See, if that helps.

Comment: OMG, @Gaurav Dave: not like this ...i need to navigaion bar  middle of right in the header.

Comment: middle of right? I didn't understood. Can you add screenshot what you want. As you have added what you are getting. So, it will be simple to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Give line height to the `nav ul li a` as same as `.logo` example [demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/aashi/3gbbqx0c/)

```
nav ul li a
{
    text-decoration:none;
    line-height:50px;
}
.logo img{
    height:50px;
}
```

Comment: is there any possibilities do without using height, i need something like standard format.thanks.

Comment: u can also use display:table; like this http://jsfiddle.net/WXLsY/296/ ... dont put height on image.my image is very big thats y i have put it

Comment: according to your answer, i got one more issue, if i add one more list to my navigation bar, it look like this,http://imgur.com/eaZ8wYE and i changed line height 100px